# Convert variance in meters in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, variance

I have made a fileInput which loads the .CSV file[dataset contains latitude and longitude] directly after user has chosen it.

```
data <- data.frame(
         Lat=c(21.076,21.99,20.95,20.00,26.57,25.70),
         long=c(60.000,67.980,61.00061.009,69.001,62.000,61.056,62.789,63.546)
)
```

Problem : I want to variance values in meters.

ui.r

```
 library(shiny)
 library(ggplot2)
 shinyUI(fluidPage(
 fileInput('file', 'Choose CSV file',
        accept=c('csv', 'comma-separated-values','.csv')),
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

 a<-reactive({
if (is.null(input$file))
   return(NULL)                
 a<-read.csv(input$file$datapath)
 a<- transform(a, var1 =var(Lat), var2= var(Long))
 # Now I want to convert this variance in meters and den display it
 a
  ))
```

Comment: The variance is the squared of the original unit of measure. If you want to express values in the original unit of measure you have to user the standard deviation not the variance.

Comment: Won't the conversion depend on the specific latitude and longitudes as well? since a standard deviation of 10 degrees latitude might be a different number of metres depending on where on earth you are, given it's not exactly spherical. How exact do you want to be?

Comment: How is this question shiny-specific? I'm not sure if I'm missing something or this is just an R (or statistics) question.

Comment: Use `spTransform` in the `sp` package to convert your `data` from lat/long to a projection in meters. (Best projection choice depends on your data, for example azimuthal equidistant centered on the mean of your lat/long might work.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the PBSmapping package.

This can convert lat/long into UTM coordinates. You need to be careful about which hemisphere you're in when setting your data. Eg. if you're in the western hemisphere you'll probably have to put a minus("-") in from of the longitudes. It's best to if you know what UTM zone you're in (you can google this).

In case you're wondering why I used a capital "X" and "Y" when I created the dataLL dataframe below is because it's a requirement of the function.

```
require(PBSmapping)

data <- data.frame(
  Lat=c(21.076,21.99,20.95,20.00,26.57,25.70,20.00,26.57,25.70),
  Long=c(60.000,67.980,61.000,61.009,69.001,62.000,61.056,62.789,63.546)
)

dataLL=as.data.frame(list(X=data$Long,Y=data$Lat))
# or if in western hemis:
#dataLL=as.data.frame(list(X=-data$Long,Y=data$Lat))

attr(dataLL,"projection")="LL"
#km=F puts the projection in meters, it automatically finds what UTM zone to use
dataUTM=convUL(dataLL,km=F)

plot(dataUTM$X,dataUTM$Y)
```